# uploading a picture using forms in symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I need to upload images using symfony, but ive not been able to do it using my form...

A simplified model is:

```
Offer:
  columns:
    id:
    name:
    pic:
    flyer:
    description:
      .
      .
      .
  relations:
    Picture:
      local: pic
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Picture_2:
      class: Picture
      local: flyer
      foreign: id
      type: one
Picture:
  columns:
    id:
    path:
    name:
      .
      .
      .
```

Now, im using a form that extends OfferForm, since I need my form to have file widgets instead of a choice widget for the fields 'pic' and 'flyer'. In the saving process, then, i need to create two instances of 'Picture' to create the two Picture objects associated to this Offer.

I have not managed to find good and complete documentation on uploading files... or at least not to my case... every tutorial or article magically uses the `$form->save()` method, and all goes fine!, but i have had multiple errors while doing this...

this is my form class:

```
class myOfferForm extends OfferForm {

  protected $statusChoices = array(
                                   'A' => 'Active',
                                   'E' => 'Expired',
                                   );
  protected $validStatus = array('A','E');

  public function configure() {
    parent::configure();

    $this->setWidgets(array(
       'id'          => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
       'name'        => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
       'picFile'     => new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
                             'file_src'     => $this->getObject()->getPicFileSrc(),
                             'is_image'     => true,
                             'with_delete'  => !is_null($this->getObject()->getPicFileSrc())
                                                               )),
       'flyerFile'   => new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
                             'file_src'     => $this->getObject()->getFlyerFileSrc(),
                             'is_image'     => true,
                             'with_delete'  => !is_null($this->getObject()->getFlyerFileSrc())
                                                               )),
       'from'        => new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
                             'format'       => '%day%/%month%/%year%',
                             'can_be_empty' => false,
                             'default'      => date('Y/m/d')
                                                  )),
       'to'          => new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
                             'format'       => '%day%/%month%/%year%',
                             'can_be_empty' => false,
                             'default'      => date('Y/m/d')
                                                  )),
       'description' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
       'status'      => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
                             'choices' => $this->statusChoices)),
       'products'    => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
                             'model'        => 'Product',
                             'table_method' => 'getActivesOrderedByName',
                             'add_empty'    => 'Check associated products',
                             'multiple'     => true,
                                                             )
                                                       ),
    ));
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
        'id'          => '',
        'name'        => 'Name *:',
        'picFile'     => 'Picture *:',
        'flyerFile'   => 'Flyer *:',
        'from'        => 'Valid From *:',
        'to'          => 'Valid To *:',
        'description' => 'Description :',
        'status'      => 'Status *:',
        'products'    => 'Associated Products :',
    ));
    $this->setValidators(array(
        'id'          => new sfValidatorChoice(array(
                             'choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('id')),
                             'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('id'),
                             'required' => false,
                                                     )),
        'name'        => new sfValidatorString(),
        'picFile'    => new sfValidatorFile(array(
                             'required'    => false,
                             'mime_types'  => 'web_images',
                             'path'        => WebPromocion::getStaticDirPath().'/',
                             'validated_file_class' => 'OfferValidatedFile',
                                                   )),
        'flyerFile'   => new sfValidatorFile(array(
                             'required'    => false,
                             'mime_types'  => 'web_images',
                             'path'        => WebPromocion::getStaticDirPath().'/',
                             'validated_file_class' => 'OfferValidatedFile',
                                                   )),
        'from'        => new sfValidatorDate(),
        'to'          => new sfValidatorDate(),
        'description' => new sfValidatorString(),
        'status'      => new sfValidatorChoice(array(
                             'choices' => $this->validStatus,
                             'required' => true,
                                                     )),
        'products'    => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
                                                 'required' => false,
                                                 'model'    => 'Product',
                                                 'column'   => 'id',
                                                 'multiple' => true, )),
    ));
    $this->validatorSchema['fotoFile_delete'] = new sfValidatorPass();
    $this->validatorSchema['flyerFile_delete'] = new sfValidatorPass();
    $this->widgetSchema->setIdFormat('offer_form_%s');
    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('offer[%s]');
  }
}
```

The OfferValidatedFile class:

```
class OfferValidatedFile extends sfValidatedFile {
  /**
   * Generates a random filename for the current file, in case
   * it already exists.
   *
   * @return string A convenient name to represent the current file
   */
  public function generateFilename()
  {
    $filename = $this->getOriginalName().$this->getExtension($this->getOriginalExtension());
    if (file_exits(WebPromocion::getStaticDirSrc().$filename)) {
      return sha1($this->getOriginalName().rand(11111, 99999)).$this->getExtension($this->getOriginalExtension());
    } else {
      return $filename;
    }
  }
}
```

And, in my action, I am doing, along with other stuff:

```
$this->form->save()
```

There is a problem. The Offer object does not have any existing Picture object to be associated with by the time the form is saved....

I think the main problem is that i want to use one form to handle submition of information related to two different objects.

So, what am I doing wrong? what am I not doing? Does someone knows a complete documentation on this subject that i could use? Is there a clean *symfonian* way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) is for the version of symfony and doctrine you're using. Unfortunately, rather than outlining initial setup for you, they include an installer script. Note that this type of setup *is* outlined elsewhere in both '[A Gentle Introduction to Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/)' as well as in other parts of '[More with Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/)' for version 1.4. Fortunately there is also a fairly verbose look at refactoring the script's form class in the first link which I think would benefit you quite a bit as well - It explains the model's processing of the form (Where you appear to be having issues) quite well, which may make debugging a little less mystifying for you.

I recommend giving it a good read. I followed this for a project a few months ago and came out of it without any issues.

Comment: I've read the recommended documentation, and it seems pretty much what I need!!! I really hope so!, but now it's late, and I'm going to sleep hehehe Il try tomorrow... In the meantime, i accept this answer! thank you very much!!

Comment: Awesome! If you have any troubles with this, feel free to shoot a question my way.